# Got "Boolean" expected "LongInt" pascal

Tags: boolean, pascal, long-integer, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

I get this error on my insertion sort algorithm:

> insertionsort.lpr(19,17) Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"

Here's the line 19 of my code

```
 while j > 0 and A[j]>key do
```

I have tried googling all over the internet but i couldn't find any syntax errors or anything.

Here's the full code if it helps :

```
program instert;
uses crt;
const
  N = 5;
var
   i:integer;
   j:integer;
   key:integer;
   A : Array[1..N] of Integer;


procedure insertionsort;
  begin
  for i := 2 to N  do
    begin
    key := A[1];
    j:= i - 1;
        while j > 0 and A[j]>key do
        begin
          A[j+1] := A[j] ;
          j := j-1;
        end;
    A[j+1] := key ;
   end;
 end;

begin
  A[1]:= 9;
  A[2]:= 6;
  A[3]:= 7;
  A[4]:= 1;
  A[5]:= 2;
  insertionsort;
end.
```

I also get the same error on the bubble sort algorithm i did. Here's the error line

> bubblesort.lpr(26,14) Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"

Here's line 26 of my algorithm:

```
 until flag = false or N = 1 ;
```

Here's the full code:

```
program bubblesort;
uses crt;

var
  flag:boolean;
  count:integer;
  temp:integer;
  N:integer;
  A : Array[1..N] of Integer;

procedure bubblesort ;
begin
  Repeat
    flag:=false;
    for count:=1 to (N-1)  do
    begin
    if A[count] > A[count + 1] then
       begin
       temp := A[count];
       A[count] := A[count + 1];
       A[count] := temp;
       flag := true;
       end;
    end;
    N := N - 1;
  until flag = false or N = 1 ;
end;

begin
  A[1]:= 9;
  A[2]:= 6;
  A[3]:= 7;
  A[4]:= 1;
  A[5]:= 2;
  N := 5;
  bubblesort;
end.
```

Comment: It's a precedence issue. `>` has lower precedence than `and`, so use parentheses: `while (j > 0) and (A[j]>key) do`. Similarly, you need `until (flag = false) or (N = 1) ;` (or just `until not flag or (N = 1) ;`)

Comment: See, for example, [Pascal Operators Precendence - TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_operators_precedence.htm)

Comment: @lurker thanks for that now the programs working

Comment: @lurker Somebody is almost as bad as I am, concerning answering in comments ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos yeah it's a pathology I suffer from. ;)

Comment: @lurker: want to write it up as an answer? It's quite a trap, especially if you come from another language.

Comment: @Jongware i can do so later today. I'm smart phone only access for several hours and its difficult to do a full answer from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pascal, boolean operators `and` and `or` have higher precedence than the comparison operators `>`, `=`, etc. So in the expression:

```
while j > 0 and A[j] > key do
```

Given that `and` has higher precedence, Pascal sees this as:

```
while (j > (0 and A[j])) > key do
```

`0 and A[j]` are evaluated as a bitwise `and` (since the arguments are integers) resulting in an integer. Then the comparison, `j > (0 and A[j])` is evaluated as a boolean result, leaving a check of that with `> key`, which is `boolean > longint`. You then get the error that a `longint` is expected instead of the `boolean` for the arithmetic comparison.

The way to fix it is to parenthesize:

```
while (j > 0) and (A[j] > key) do ...
```

The same issue applies with this statement:

```
until flag = false or N = 1 ;
```

which yields an error because `or` is higher precedence than `=`. So you can parenthesize:

```
until (flag = false) or (N = 1);
```

Or, more canonical for booleans:

```
until not flag or (N = 1);    // NOTE: 'not' is higher precedence than 'or'
```

When in doubt about the precedence of operators, parenthesizing is a good idea, as it removes the doubt about what order operations are going to occur.